# Как git работает со ссылками

Tags: git, gitlab

Здравствуйте.
Мне нужно завести проект в gitlab. В проекте есть symlink'и как на директории так и на файлы. Мой вопрос такой, как git работает со ссылками? Имеет ли значение идет ссылка на файл или директорию? Если я хочу добавить их в .gitignore, мне просто добавлять их как конкретные файлы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**git** сохраняет **symlink** так же как файл в blob. При **checkout** он создаст его как **symlink** и не важно есть ли оригинальный файл/директория.

Вы можете добавить их в **.gitignore** как простые файлы по имени.

Comment: вы можете отметить ответ как принятый - галочка рядом с ответом. либо подождать другие ответы и выюрать лучший.